# Blender 2.8x do not work

Tags: interface, installation, opengl, versions, hardware

I've searched for an answer to my problem and didn't find any. So, I'm gonna ask.
My hardware requirement configuration is at it's minimum; at some aspects, over. So why I can't make Blender 2.8x work?
Here are the config:

[enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACCrx.png)

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeSSR.png)
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tehHC.png)
[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7b27l.png)
[4](https://i.imgur.com/GmV8wbE.png)
[5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJBhM.png)
[6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGxCD.png)

Comment: Hello :). I'm afraid the GPU is too old and not fully supported. You can try [Blender 2.79](https://www.blender.org/download/previous-versions/) instead.

Comment: The [minimum requirement](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/) for running Blender with an AMD GPU is GCN first generation or later.

Comment: Sad... Anyways, thank you, guys!